# Change class of property

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Please excuse any wrong use of programming terminology, I am looking for ios6 solutions to my problem:

I have the property in my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AClass *myExample;
```

but in my .m file I actually might want _myExample to be AClass, BClass or CClass.

```
_myExample = [[BClass alloc] init]; // incompatible pointer types
```

What is the best way to implement this

Comment: Do `AClass`, `BClass`, and `CClass` share a common superclass? Do they have a common interface? What messages do you want to send these objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably factor out what you need to be true about all three of `AClass`, `BClass` and `CCLass` into a protocol, say `ICDoSomethingProtocol` and then declare the property to be of type `id <NSObject, ICDoSomethingProtocol> myExample` rather than `AClass *`.

You could skip the protocol and just go with `id <NSObject>` but you'll get less compile-time checking.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should create XClass and make AClass, BClass, and CClass subclasses of XClass.  Then use `@property (nonatomic, strong) XClass *myExample;`  But if you're "lazy" (which is not a programming sin) you can use the pre-exiting class of NSObject, or simply declare the property as `@property (nonatomic, strong) id myExample;`.  (Note that there is no `*`.)

In any of these cases you will need to (or at least probably should) "cast" the property to the correct subclass before using it (except for calling methods of a superclass).  Eg, `int aValue = [(BClass*)self.myExample doSomeOperationOnBClass];`.

To avoid the need to cast like this (and the associated confusion), it's not uncommon to simply declare separate properties for the three classes, even though two of the three will always be unused.  (Again, laziness is not a programming sin.)

Comment: Thank you, this answer was helpful too.